# One computer, two desktops?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, desktop, macros

Can I make my single computer run multiple desktops at the same time. 
I need one desktop that will work in the background until I decide to switch back to it from the other regular everyday desktop. 
So the desktops would need to work simultaneously, example, while I'm using a macro software on desktop1 to do something boring, I am playing fullscreen games on desktop2.

Is there some kind of software? Do I need extra hardware like maybe another screen?

Comment: Are you willing to tell us a little about your computer setup; OS, # of monitors, etc.?

Comment: Windows XP, 1 monitor.... You don't really need much info I guess, ask specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see it there are two options to you

- *Use a VM*. This will let the boring process run minimized and it should work fine. Any macro software will work with this solution but they will act like two whole computers and it will use more of the host system's resources (ram, cpu. ect.)
- *Use Remote desktop on to the same machine*. This gets around all of the resource issues with a vm, but the macro software may not work if the RDP window is minimized (I think it should still work if it is open but in the background). This only works on server versions of windows unless you are willing to [replace some of the dll's](http://www.mydigitallife.info/enable-multiple-concurrent-remote-desktop-connections-or-sessions-in-windows-xp/) to allow multiple concurrent logons. (The instructions and dll's will be different for Vista and 7)

Whichever solution works best for you, you should go with that one.

If you do get another screen you can use a macro program to do the work in the same session as you, but I have not seen one that does not steal the focus away (unless it is specifically designed for the program it is controlling like a MMO botting program), so you would not be able to play very fast pace games but simple things like internet browsing would work fine (your mouse-wheel won't though) I do that exact setup my self some times.

Comment: Yeah I'm actually trying to use it for a very boooring browser game. If you have any suggestions on how to do it they are most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Desktops (Windows Sysinternals)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881).

Comment: I've had good luck with this app.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use a virtual desktop software.
Ask Google for a bunch of them.

I use this one: http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/ (Free and OpenSource)
But you have lots of others.

Comment: I suppose it has everything I asked, primarily macro enabled actions. Downloading and tnx a lot.

Comment: Oops wait. Doesn't meet all requirements. It just loads different set of windows when I switch desktops. So the macro that I try to run doesn't "stay" in the other desktop and do it's job. I need new fresh unaffected desktop, not set of windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect and (simultaneously) use up to three monitors using the on-board graphics capability. If you have monitors that only support DVI, you can purchase a HDMI-to-DVI or DisplayPort-to-DVI adaptor (and use your existing DVI-to-DVI cable) or you can purchase a HDMI-to-DVI or DisplayPort-to-DVI cable. These are relatively inexpensive.